# Runtime error 0x800a139e in new MVC project?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

when creating and running a completely blank new MvcApplication (Internet site template, VS2012 SP1, MVC4 on Win8), the debug-output shows:

```
Exception was thrown at line 5108, column 4 in http://localhost:64687/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js
0x800a139e - Laufzeitfehler in JavaScript: SyntaxError
```

jQuery is 1.7.1.1

I get this error also in other projects with other jQuery-Versions.
What could be the reason?

Thanks for hints.

Edit: the line number in other projects is 4224 or 3983 in jquery-1.9.1.js.
Sorry for the weak description, but I can't really get a grip on the error. :(

Comment: Updating jQuery doesn't help: Exception was thrown at line 4224, column 4 in http://localhost:64687/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js
0x800a139e - Laufzeitfehler in JavaScript: SyntaxError

Comment: I wonder if the debugger could be configured to break at such errors.

Answer (score 1):

I found this code when I looked in jquery-1.7.1.js. The matches.call is line 5108... It looks like jquery is intentionally causing this exception, so I'm going to ignore it and move on. Someone else suggested on another board that jquery was trying to interoperate with Sizzle.

You can probably just delete the try-catch block if you want.

```
try {
    // This should fail with an exception
    // Gecko does not error, returns false instead
    matches.call( document.documentElement, "[test!='']:sizzle" );

    catch( pseudoError ) {
        pseudoWorks = true;
    }
}
```